# "An error occurred in the deployment tool" Visual Studio issue with deploying to aws keep telling this

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio

"An error occurred in the deployment tool" Visual Studio issue with deploying to aws keep telling this...
Whatever the option we choose the result is same issue.
[image]

Comment: Hello! I've reached out to the .NET on AWS team to gain some more advice on what's best to debug this issue in this case. I'll let you know when I get something back.

Comment: same has been added in github as well...
https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/issues/310

Comment: Try just doing ‘dotnet aws deploy’ on the command line and please let us know the output

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to delpoy to Elastic Beanstalk on Linux, after adding the following policies to my user it worked (create multiples groups and assign them to your user. And most probably not all of them are necessary, but whatever):

- AmazonSageMakerServiceCatalogProductsCloudformationServiceRolePolicy
- AWSCloudFormationFullAccess
- AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk
- AWSCodeDeployRoleForCloudFormation
- AWSDeepRacerCloudFormationAccessPolicy
- AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
- AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy
- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
- IAMFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonSSMFullAccess
- AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess
- AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole
- AmazonS3OutpostsFullAccess
- AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess
- EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilderECRContainerBuilds

Alternatively you can check the error details with this command:

```
dotnet aws deploy --profile [your-profile-name] --region [your-region] --project-path [path-to-your-web-api-csproj]
```